# Display description instead of code in .net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table where I store all the different code/value keywords that I need in my app:

```
public class Keyword 
{
  public int id { get; set;}
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string valuecode { get; set; }
  public string valuename { get; set; }
}
```

Then I use Keyword to store records like these

```
name         valuecode   valuename   
.DealState   1           Draft
.DealState   2           Final
.DealState   3           Cancelled
.DealType    NEW         New Business
.DealType    RNW         Renewal
.DealType    WFA         Waiting for approval
```

Then in other models I have fields that are filled using these keywords. For example,

```
public class Deal 
{
   ....
   public string state { get; set; }
   public string type { get; set; }
   ....
}
```

I have managed to have the fields filled with "valuecode" while displaying "valuename" in Create and Edit views (I use DropDownList with a SelectList built in the controller), but I cannot find a way to display valuename instead of valuecode in Index and Details views.

I'm trying to pass the same SelectList in the ViewBag for Index, but then I do not know which syntax to use in order to replace the "state" code with the state "description" for each record returned.

Any hint?

PS: I'm quite new to .net and mvc, usually work with RoR and ActiveRecord...

> **EDIT**

In my KeywordController I have a method

```
public SelectList selectKeywordValues(string kwname, object selectedKeyword = null)
{
    var keywordsQuery = from d in db.Keywords
                           where d.name == kwname
                           orderby d.valuename
                           select d;
    SelectList kwlist = new SelectList(keywordsQuery, "valuecode", "valuename", selectedKeyword);
    return kwlist;
}
```

Then in my DealController i have the index method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var kw = new KeywordController();
   ViewBag.state = kw.selectKeywordValues(".DealState");
   return View(db.Deals.ToList());
}
```

Comment: show the code you tried for your index/detail views & action method.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [view model](http://www.rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp.net-mvc-applications) called DealViewModel that contains DealState and DealType properties. Then populate the DealViewModel with joins in LINQ before passing to the views that reference the view model.

Another approach is to use enums in EF5.

Comment: Cannot use enums because keyword values must be modifiable by the user. Using ViewModel is a good idea, but I still have to understand what it is and how it works; good for next refactoring round...

Comment: I added a link in the answer about view model usage. In this case you could do the same substitution as in your solution but it would be more explicit to assign them to dedicated properties to make the final code more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLVED**

In DealController the index method is the following

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var kw = new KeywordController();
        SelectList states = kw.selectKeywordValues(".DealState");
        SelectList types = kw.selectKeywordValues(".DealType");
        foreach (var item in db.Deals.ToList())
        {
            SelectListItem mystate = states.Where(row => row.Value == item.state).ElementAt(0);
            SelectListItem mytype = types.Where(row => row.Value == item.type).ElementAt(0);
            item.state = mystate.Text;
            item.type = mytype.Text;
        }
        return View(db.Deals.ToList());
    }
```

Now the db.Deals.ToList() is filled with descriptions and not with codes.